# Is it possible to create a property from another property within the same prototype object?

Tags: javascript

New to coding:
I'm trying to do something like this in Javascript:

```
function Calculator(a,b){
 this.a=a;
 this.b=b;
 this.c=a*b;
 this.d=c;
}

var myTiCalc = new Calculator(1,2);
alert(myTiCalc.d);
```

So that it prints "d" in an alert box. However I keep getting a "Nan" in the alert.

Appreciate your expertise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function Calculator(a,b){
 this.a=a;
 this.b=b;
 this.c=a*b;
 this.d=this.c;
}

var myTiCalc = new Calculator(1,2);
alert(myTiCalc.d);
```

In the line #5 you put `this.d=c;` instead of `this.d=this.c`. Variable `c` was not defined anywhere. What I think you need is to assign property `c` to `d` of the Calculator object, so you need to call it with the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to assign the `var c`.

Or you can do `this.d = this.c;`

```js
function Calculator(a,b){
 this.a=a;
 this.b=b;
 this.eg = a*b;
 var c = a*b;
 this.d=c;
 this.d2 = this.eg;
}

var myTiCalc = new Calculator(1,2);
console.log(myTiCalc.d);
console.log(myTiCalc.d2);
```